# Is there a way to pass additional information (e.g. Description) to the PayPal payment-processor?

Tags: payment-processor, paypal

We are using PayPal as our payment processor and Xero for our accounting. When reconciling the PayPal items generated from CiviCRM we noticed a field called "Description" that is usually empty. Is there any way of passing information to that PayPal field from a CiviContribute form? It would be monumentally helpful when reconcilling if we could pass simple descriptions like "Dues" or "Building Fund" to PayPal that we could then see in Xero (and use reconcilliation rules with).  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Civi does send description to paypal. You can alter them by implementing [hook_civicrm_alterPaymentProcessorParams](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_alterPaymentProcessorParams/)() hook

Comment: Brilliant!. Thanks. I'll get the people who work at that level on our site to look into that.